# protoc-gen-go cannot run in terminal but can run in GoLand IDE

Tags: go, terminal, protocol-buffers, goland, protoc

I want to ask, I'm learning about generating protobuf for golang. But I have a little bit problem. I can generate it when I use GoLand, but I can't when use the terminal. Even I try `which protoc-gen-go` in terminal it said not found. Why it does happen?

This is my Makefile code for generating protobuf:

```
pb:
    rm -rf protobuf && \
    mkdir protobuf && \
    protoc --proto_path=proto --go_out=protobuf --go_opt=paths=source_relative \
    --go-grpc_out=protobuf --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative \
    route.proto
```

This is a screenshot from [GoLand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIm82.png)

This is a screenshot from [terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kl5fu.jpg)

Comment: Check if your `.../go/bin` directory is added to `PATH` environment variable? Maybe it works in goland terminal because goland added `$GOPATH/bin` directory to `PATH` automatically (just guessing, I'm not goland user)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, this is my first time using Mac for development so I still don't familiar with how to set PATH env in there, I already set it but it doesn't work in the first place. So I need to search how to configure it first. After that, it works perfectly.